# Mongoose: Update nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have following JSON structure,

```
{
  "projectId": "service-request-service",
  "projectVersion": [{
    "version":"1",
    "localConfig": [{
      "port": "3003",
      "mongoURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest",
      "MQ": "RMQ",
      "logLevel": "2",
      "version": "1.1",
      "created": "03-06-2018 03:11:00 PM",
      "active": "N"
    },
    {
      "port": "3004",
      "mongoURI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/serviceRequest",
      "MQ": "IMQ",
      "logLevel": "1",
      "version": "1.2",
      "created": "07-06-2018 03:11:00 PM",
      "active": "Y"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Now, I want to update all `port` and `active` values of `localConfig`. I tried using different ways,

1. using `markModified`

   ```
   ProjectConfig.findOne({'projectId' : projectId,
       'projectVersion.version' : version})
       .exec(function(err,pc){

   pc.projectVersion[0].localConfig[0].active = "N";
   pc.projectVersion[0].localConfig[0].port = "5555";

   pc.markModified('localConfig');

   pc.save(function(err,result){
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
       console.log("## SUCCESSFULLY SAVED  ");
   });

   });
   ```
2. Iterating using `for` loop.

   ```
    ProjectConfig.findOne({'projectId' : projectId,
   'projectVersion.version' : version}).exec(function(err,pc){

   for(i = 0; i < pc.projectVersion.length ; i++){                    
       for(j = 0; j < pc.projectVersion[i][envQuery].length ; j++){ 
           pc.projectVersion[i][envQuery][j].active = 'N';
           pc.projectVersion[i][envQuery][j].port = '5555';
       }
   }

   pc.save(function (err, result) {
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
       console.log("## SUCCESSFULLY SAVED  ");
   });        
   });
   ```
3. Using `arrayFilters`,

   ```
   let conditions = {};
   let update = {$set: {"projectVersion.$[i].localConfig.$[].port": "5555"}};
   let options = {arrayFilters:[{"i.version":"1"}]};
   pc.update(conditions,update,options,function(err,result){
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       }
       console.log("## SUCCESSFULLY SAVED  ");
   });
   ```

But, I am getting below error.

```
MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]
```

Please provide me the way to update document.

Current version of `MongoDB : v3.6.6` &     `Mongoose : ^5.0.14`

Answer (score 0):

Using `arrayFilters`, I am not applying `update` method on scheme rather applying on object return by `find` method.
When I directly apply `update` method on schema, its working.

```
let conditions = { "projectId" : "32804-service-request-service" };
            let update = { $set: {
                                "projectVersion.$[i].localConfig.$[j].port" : "5555",
                                }
                        };
            let options = {arrayFilters:[{"i.version":"1" },{ "j.port" : "3003"}]};
            ProjectConfig.update(conditions, update, options, function(err,result){
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        title: 'An error occurred',
                        error: err
                    });
                }
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'SUCCESS',
                    obj: result  
                });
            });
```